# ¿Cómo puedo hacer funcionar un bucle encima de otro?

Tags: javascript

Me era muy díficil describir mi problema en el título. Ya he mirado la "solución" pero lo resuelve de una manera diferente a la que yo estaba intentando, y realmente me interesa saber si de mi manera era posible hacerlo. Resulta que tengo esto:

```js
//Setup
var contacts = [
    {
        "firstName": "Akira",
        "lastName": "Laine",
        "number": "0543236543",
        "likes": ["Pizza", "Coding", "Brownie Points"]
    },
    {
        "firstName": "Harry",
        "lastName": "Potter",
        "number": "0994372684",
        "likes": ["Hogwarts", "Magic", "Hagrid"]
    },
    {
        "firstName": "Sherlock",
        "lastName": "Holmes",
        "number": "0487345643",
        "likes": ["Intriguing Cases", "Violin"]
    },
    {
        "firstName": "Kristian",
        "lastName": "Vos",
        "number": "unknown",
        "likes": ["JavaScript", "Gaming", "Foxes"]
    }
];
```

Y debo hacer una función que ingresando el parámetro de "firstName" (por ejemplo, Akira) y una propiedad (por ejemplo likes) responda con los valores correspondientes a la propiedad del firstName que se ingresó (es decir, en el caso de poner de parámetros Akira y likes, la función responde con ["Pizza", "Coding", "Brownie Points"].

En el caso de que la propiedad no exista, la función devuelve "No such property". En el caso de que el firstName ingresado no exista, la función devuelve "No such contact".

```js
function lookUpProfile(name, prop){
// Only change code below this line
    for (let i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++){
    if (contacts[i].firstName == name && (contacts[i].hasOwnProperty(prop)) == true) {
        return contacts[i][prop]
    }
    else if (contacts[i].firstName !== name){
        return "No such contact"
    }
    else if (contacts[i].hasOwnProperty(prop) == false ){
        return "No such property"
    }
    }
}
```

Ahí la función que he hecho que funciona pero sólo si coincide que los parámetros a ingresar son los del primer objeto como Akira (es decir, contacts[0]). Por qué hasta dónde yo creía los bucles son útiles porque se repiten, pero sin embargo como en la primera iteración se encuentra contacts[0], el bucle no sigue, yo me gustaría que siguiese hasta contacts[1] para que al final diese con el firstName correcto.

Para eso he intentando envolver ese loop en otro pero sigue existiendo el mismo problema. Alguien me puede aclarar esta confusión que tengo con los bucles y si añadiendo algún detalle se puede hacer realmente para que el bucle no pare y avance a contacts[1] y realmente compruebe todos los objetos.

Comment: En la primera iteración del bucle (i = 0), estás evaluando el primer elemento de `contacts`. Si el `name` name que le has pasado a la función no coincide con el primero (Akira, i = 0), entonces pasa al `else if (contacts[i].firstName !== name) {...}` y termina la ejecución de la función devolviendo 'No such contact'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como te comenta @DavidSilva, tienes un problema en la forma que estás evaluando tus condiciones.

**PROBLEMA**

Dado un `array` que contiene objetos, se desea realizar un búsqueda en cada elemento del `array` usando como filtro 2 valores que han sido pasados como argumento a la función de búsqueda.
Los elementos del array tienen un formato común: son objetos con par clave valor.
Los parámetros de búsqueda se establecen de tal manera que el primer parámetro es el valor de la propiedad `firstName` de un objeto, y el segundo parámetro es nombre de alguna propiedad del objeto.

La función ha de devolver el valor asociado al segundo parámetro (propiedad) en caso que consiga una coincidencia, o el mensaje "No such property". En caso que no se encuentre una coincidencia debe devolver el mensaje "No such contact".

**SOLUCIÓN**

Para lograr el objetivo vamos a usar un bucle `foreach` para recorrer los elementos de nuestro `array`. Compararemos el parámetro de entrada con el valor de `element.firstName`. En caso de conseguir una coincidencia, buscaremos en el elemento si existe una propiedad con el nombre que hemos pasado como segundo parámetro a la búsqueda, para esto usaremos el método `hasOwnProperty(property)`. Si la propiedad existe devolvemos su valor, si la propiedad no existe devolvemos el mensaje apropiado.
Si la búsqueda no devuelve resultado debemos devolver el mensaje apropiado.

Crearemos una función llamada (como propone el OP)`lookUpProfile(firstName, property)`, a la cual le pasamos 2 parámetros.

El código puede quedar de la siguiente manera:

```js
 var contacts = [
        {
            "firstName": "Akira",
            "lastName": "Laine",
            "number": "0543236543",
            "likes": ["Pizza", "Coding", "Brownie Points"]
        },
        {
            "firstName": "Harry",
            "lastName": "Potter",
            "number": "0994372684",
            "likes": ["Hogwarts", "Magic", "Hagrid"]
        },
        {
            "firstName": "Sherlock",
            "lastName": "Holmes",
            "number": "0487345643",
            "likes": ["Intriguing Cases", "Violin"]
        },
        {
            "firstName": "Kristian",
            "lastName": "Vos",
            "number": "unknown",
            "likes": ["JavaScript", "Gaming", "Foxes"]
        }
        ];

        function lookUpProfile(firstName, property) {
            var message = 'No such contact';
           for(let element of contacts){
                if(element.firstName.toUpperCase() == firstName.toUpperCase()) {
                    message = element.hasOwnProperty(property) ? element[property] : 'No such property';
                }
            }
            return message;
        }
        var button = document.getElementById('button-lookup');
        button.onclick = function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var firstName = document.getElementById('firstName').value.trim();
            var property = document.getElementById('property').value.trim();
            var message = lookUpProfile(firstName, property);
            window.alert(message);
        }
```

```html
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row justify-content-center mt-4">
            <div class="col-4 col-md-3">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstName" placeholder="Profile's firstname" aria-label="Profile's firstname">
            </div>
            <div class="col-6 col-md-4">
                <div class="input-group mb-3">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="property" placeholder="Profile's property" aria-label="Profile's property" aria-describedby="button-lookup">
                    <div class="input-group-append">
                        <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="button" id="button-lookup">Look Up</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Espero que se la respuesta que estás buscando.

**NOTA**

Como en tu pregunta pides una aclaratoria del uso del bucle `for` y yo he usado el método `for of` de un `Array`, te haré la siguiente acotación.

Un bucle `for` tal como lo conocemos, está diseñado, entre otras cosas, para recorrer un conjunto u objeto iterable. Un `array` es un objeto iterable. Por lo tanto podemos recorrer sus elementos accediendo al índice de posición de cada uno de ellos.

En tu pregunta planteas que quieres que se pueda recorrer todo el `array` o al menos que la búsqueda continúe si no encuentras coincidencia en el primer elemento. Tal como te comentó @DavidSilva, tienes un problema en la forma que evalúas tu condición.

Un forma de hacer uso del bucle `for` para este ejemplo sería la siguiente:

```
for (var i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++) {
    if (contacts[i].firstName == firstName){
        var obj =  contacts[i];
        message = obj.hasOwnProperty(property) ? obj[property] : 'No such property';
        break;
    }
}
```

El resultado es el desado. Debes notar que he usado la sentencia `break` para salir del bucle. Lo hago para que se detenga la búsqueda. ¿Qué pasa si 2 o más contactos tienen el mismo nombre? Nuestro bucle `for` devolverá el primero que encuentre.
Si no usamos la sentencia `break`, entonces el bucle for se ejecutará hasta el final y nuestra función devolverá la última coincidencia que encuentre.

Espero que eso aclare tu duda.

Comment: @Bryro, una pregunta. Veo que editaste mi respuesta  recientemente, tu motivo fue 'bucle for each deprecated' sin embargo yo no usé dicho bucle, usé el método forEach() del objeto Array. ¿Ese método también está en deprecated?